# Why is destructor of `boost::multi_array_ref` non-virtual?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-array

The relationship among `const_multi_array_ref`, `multi_array_ref` and `multi_array` is as follows:

- `multi_array_ref` is derived from `const_multi_array_ref`
- `multi_array` is derived from `multi_arry_ref`

However, the destructors of `const_multi_array_ref` and `multi_array_ref` are non-virtual. In fact they do not have an explicitly implemented destructor. Only `multi_array` has a one. Does this imply the following usage is not recommended?

```
multi_array_ref<float, 2> * = new multi_array<float, 2>(extents[3][3]);
```

If so, why?

Comment: please avoid using pointers in boost. boost is designed mostly to utilize usage of smart pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multi_array` library classes aren't designed for dynamic polymorphism. They don't have any virtual functions, so it doesn't look reasonable to make destructor virtual too. It's common STL-like design, `multi_array_ref` is just used as unified interface adapter for data owning and non-owning cases.

Your usage sample is highly not recommended - it will lead to memory leak because `multi_array` destructor will not be executed on `delete` call.

But it will be safe to access `multi_array` instance via reference or pointer to `multi_array_ref`.